# Sub-resource creation url

Tags: rest, hateoas, hal-json

Lets assume we have some `main-resource` and a related `sub-resource` with 1-n relation;

User of the API can:

1. list main-resources so `GET /main-resources` endpoint.
2. list sub-resources so `GET /sub-resources` endpoint.
3. list sub-resources of a `main-resource` so one or both of;

   1. `GET /main-resources/{main-id}/sub-resources`
   2. `GET /sub-resouces?main={main-id}`
4. create a `sub-resource` under a `main-resource`

   1. `POST /main-resource/{main-id}/sub-resouces`: Which has the benefit of hierarchy, but in order to support this one needs to provide another set of endpoints(list, create, update, delete).
   2. `POST /sub-resouces?main={main-id}`: Which has the benefit of having embedded id inside URL. A middleware can handle and inject provided values into request itself.
5. create a `sub-resource` with all parameters in body `POST /sub-resources`

Is providing a URI with `main={main-id}` query parameter embedded a good way to solve this or should I go with the route of hierarchical URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a true REST environment the spelling of URIs is not of importance as long as the characters used in the URI adhere to the URI specification. While RFC 3986 states that

> The path component contains data, **usually organized in hierarchical form**, that, along with data in the non-hierarchical query component (Section 3.4), serves to identify a resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority (if any). The path is terminated by the first question mark ("?") and number sign ("#") character, or by the end of the URI. ([Source](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.3))

it does not state that a URI has to have a hierarchical structure assigned to it. A URI as a whole is a pointer to a resource and as such a combination of various URIs may give the impression of some hierarchy involved. The actual information of whether URIs have some hierarchical structure to it should though stem from link relations that are attached to URIs. These can be [registered names](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) like `up`, `fist`, `last`, `next`, `prev` and the like or [Web linking extensions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288#section-2.1.2) such as `https://acme.org/rel/parent` which acts more like a predicate in a Semantic Web relation basically stating that the URI at hand is a parent to the current resource. Don't confuse rel-URIs for real URIs though. Such rel-URIs do not necessarily need to point to an actual resource or even to a documentation. Such link relation extensions though my be defined by media-types or certain profiles.

In a perfect world the URI though is only used to send the request to the actual server. A client won't parse or try to extract some knowledge off an URI as it will use accompanying link relation names to determine whether the URI is of relevance to the task at hand or not. REST is full of such "indirection" mechanism in order to help decoupling clients from servers.

I.e. what is the difference between a URI like `https://acme.org/api/users/1` and `https://acme.org/api/3f067d90-8b55-4b60-befc-1ce124b4e080`? Developers in the first case might be tempted to create a user object representing the data returned by the URI invoked. Over time the response format might break as stuff is renamed, removed and replaced by other stuff. This is what Fielding called [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) which REST shouldn't have.

The second URI doesn't give you a clue on what content it returns, and you might start questioning on what benefit it brings then. While you might not be aware of what actual content the service returns for such URIs, you know at least that your client is able to process the data somehow as otherwise the service would have responded with a `406 Not Acceptable` response. So, content-type negotiation ensures that your client will with high certainty receive data it is able to process. Maintaining interoperability in a domain that is likely to change over time is one of RESTs strong benefits and selling points. Depending on the capabilities of your client and the service, you might receive a tailored response-format, which is only applicable to that particular service, or receive a more general-purpose one, like HTML i.e.. Your client basically needs a mapping to translate the received representation format into something your application then can use. As mentioned, REST is probably all about introducing indirections for the purpose of decoupling clients from servers. The benefit for going this indirection however is that once you have it working it will work with responses issued not only from that server but for any other service that also supports returning that media type format. And just think a minute what options your client has when it supports a couple of general-purpose formats. It then can basically communicate and interoperate with various other services in that ecosystem without a need for you touching it. This is how browsers operate on the Web for decades now.

This is exactly why I think that this phrase of Fielding is probably one of the most important ones but also the one that is ignored and or misinterpreted by most in the domain of REST:

> A REST API should spend almost all of its descriptive effort in defining the media type(s) used for representing resources and driving application state, or in defining extended relation names and/or hypertext-enabled mark-up for existing standard media types. ([Source](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven))

So, in a true REST environment the form of the URI is unimportant as clients rely on other mechanisms to determine whether to use that URI or not. Even for so called "REST APIs" that do not really care about the true meaning of REST and treat it more like old-school RPC the question at hands is probably very opinionated and there probably isn't that one fits all solution. If your framework supports injecting stuff based on the presence of certain query parameters, use that. If you prefer the more hierarchical structure of URIs, go for those. There isn't a right or wrong in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

According to the URI standard when you have a hierarchical relationship between resources, then better to add it to the path instead of the query. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#page-22 Sometimes it is better to describe the relation itself, not just the sub-resource, but that happens only if the sub-resource can belong to multiple main resources, which is n:m relationship.

Comment: in order to support that I need to go with `/main-resources/{main-id}/sub-resources` route. which make same resource available on two different endpoints. Does it not contradict with the one resource should only available from one endpoint? I have read so many things I might be mixing up.

Comment: @YakupTürkan I edited the answer. By definition if one sub-resource can belong to multiple main resources then it is n:m relationship, not 1:n relationship. You can do something like `/main-resources/{main-id}/sub-resource-relationships` so you describe the relationship between the main and sub resources instead of the sub-resource itself.

Comment: It does not belong to other resources, it is there to provide listing and editing to another set of user(admin). or is it better to provide two different APIs to cover such need?

Comment: @YakupTürkan Admin is a role in access control, it should not be a separate resource normally.

Comment: but in a normal workflow of admin they could review all `sub-resources` without thinking about which `main-resource` it belongs to. If i go with only one URL for `/main-resources/{main-id}/sub-resources` for `sub-resource` it would lead to some strange contraption that requests `sub-resources` of a `main-resource` and tries to paginate over that.

Comment: @YakupTürkan Your problem does not make much sense. If the `{main-id}` is not enough to identify the `sub-resource`, then it is n:m relationship and not 1:n relationship. Except if there can be free `sub-resources` which can be taken by `main-resources` one for one `main-resource`. In that case you need a `{sub-id}` and a list of `sub-resources` too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248520/discussion-between-yakup-turkan-and-inf3rno).

Comment: @YakupTürkan As inf3rno already stated authentication and authorization should be part of the request itself and as such the same URI may return different results for different users. That's totally fine. In regards how you should design your "system". Try to picture how you'd solve this if you'd interact with a traditional Web based solution. REST just uses the same concepts. It just may use different representation formats to express the same.

Comment: @RomanVottner in order to return different responses for different users an endpoint must be generic right? In that case `/sub-resources?main={main-id}` is the one you suggest?

Comment: @YakupTürkan the logic in the back needs to support it, of course. But that does not necessarily mean that it needs to be generic in your quoted way. A resource like `/main/1/sub` is as much able to return the same response as `/sub?main=1` is. URIs after all do not have the hierarchical structure embedded into them. To a client these URIs should be opaque and only be relevant to the server.